# Iam getting a unknown logical error in displaying text

Tags: oop

So I have made a game of deck of cards which allows the user to display 1 card at a time,however when i go to check my deck of cards is working, it seems to print out just a bunch of empty values like "  of  ",but then i printed out the whole deck and it has only worked for all the diamond suit values,every other suit value is just blank.

```
class Deck
    {
        // Fields
        public List<Card> Cards { get; private set; } = new List<Card>();

        // Constructor 
        public Deck()
        {
            CreateStandardDeck();
        }
        
        // Fill up the deck when a new object is instansiated
        private void CreateStandardDeck()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card());
            }
        }

        // Method which shows user all cards in current deck
        public void DisplayDeck()
        {
            foreach(var card in Cards) Console.WriteLine(card);
        }
```

```
class Card
    {
        // Fields 
        public string Suit { get; private set; }
        public string Value { get; private set; }

        private List<string> Suits = new List<string> { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };
        private List<string> Values = new List<string> { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                                                         "Ace", "Queen", "Jack", "King"};

        // keep track off all used cards
        public static List<string> usedCards = new List<string>();

        // Constructor
        public Card()
        {
            foreach (var suit in Suits)
            {
                foreach (var value in Values)
                {
                    string card = value.ToString() + "of" + suit.ToString();

                    if (!usedCards.Contains(card))
                    {
                        usedCards.Add(value.ToString() + "of" + suit.ToString());
                        Suit = suit;
                        Value = value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Value} of {Suit}";
    }
```

MAIN

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call method to start the program
            DrawCards();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Short program which deals one card from deck at a time and also shuffles the deck
        private static void DrawCards()
        {
            Deck newDeck = new Deck();

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to shuffle your deck of cards? (type yes)");
            string option = Console.ReadLine();
            if(option.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                newDeck.Shuffle();
                Console.Clear();
            }

            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to draw a card?" +
                                  "\n> Type 'yes' for yes\n> Type 'anything else' for no");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                
                if (answer.ToLower() == "yes")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine($"> {newDeck.Deal()}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No more cards will be drawn..");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are the `Deck`’s `Shuffle` and `Deal` methods? You should put a break point right after the line … `Deck newDeck = new Deck();` … it is not returning what you are expecting. Also, I would re-think the `Card` object… it is doing too much and most of the randomness should be done in the `Deck` class. A `Card` is a `Card` and that is it.

Comment: [Eric Lippert: How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic inside of Card is a bit convoluted and should be contained in the upper class Deck.

With the card creation logic in deck, you have a couple of simple loops to create a full deck of cards.  Each deck can have its own types of "suits" and any number of cards per suit.

Here is a simple example of what I mentioned above.

```
public class Card
{
    public string Suit { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

// Would be better as a class, for test purposes this is just a function
//
private void CreateDeck()
{
    var cardsPerSuit = 13;
    var suits = new string[] { "Spade", "Diamond", "Club", "Heart" };

    var deck = new List<Card>();

    for (int i = 0; i < suits.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < cardsPerSuit; ii++)
        {
            deck.Add(new Card()
            {
                Suit = suits[i],
                Number = ii + 1
            });
        }
    }
}
```

To Get a pretty name for the number such as Ace, King, etc.. you can use a function on the card (or elsewhere if you pass the card as a parameter).

```
public string GetNumberAsName()
{
    if (Number == 1)
    {
        return "Ace";
    }
    else if (Number == 11)
    {
        return "Jack";
    }
    else if (Number == 12)
    {
        return "Queen";
    }
    else if (Number == 13)
    {
        return "King";
    }

    return Number.ToString();
}
```

It would be best to just store this information for quick access.  Since you do not allow set on the number in your card class, you do not have to worry about the pretty name becoming out of sync with the number.

Comment: You can have a function that does the display for you. You could add a property for it on card with a getter that calls the GetCardNumberAsName() function

Comment: I added a simple example of converting the number to pretty name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a simplified version of your approach.

The `Card` class…

```
public class Card {
  public string Suit { get; }
  public string Value { get; }
  
  public Card(string suit, string value) {
    Suit = suit;
    Value = value;
  }

  public override string ToString() => $"{Value} of {Suit}";
}
```

Then the `Deck` class which should do most of the work…

```
public class Deck {
  public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

  public Deck() {
    Cards = GetNewDeck();
  }

  public void DisplayDeck() {
    foreach (var card in Cards)
      Console.WriteLine(card);
  }
  
  public List<Card> GetNewDeck() {
    List<string> Suits = new List<string> { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", };
    List<string> Values = new List<string> { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };
    List<Card> newDeck = new List<Card>();
    foreach (var suit in Suits) {
      foreach (var value in Values) {
        newDeck.Add(new Card(suit, value));
      }
    }
    return newDeck;
  }
  
  public void ShuffleDeck() {
    // ???
  }
  
  public void DealCards() {
    // ??
  }
}
```